# Change an object's value in a js file from an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object (response) inside the  of a .html file. I want to set an object (response1) in a Global.js file inside the same directory as response.

So my directories look like:

/res/Global.js --> This one has response1

/res/Response.html --> This one has response inside a  tag

Global.js looks like

```
var response1 = null;

export default {
  response1;
}
```

I want smt like `Global.response1 = response;`

Comment: Are you missing some tags? This is not plain JS I guess

Comment: Global.js is complete. I can export import object to from other .js files. But not from .html files.

Comment: You could use the window object or session/localStorage, or a dom-node to store the value then retrieve it from wherever you like so long as the file that's retrieving it is being loaded.